# Failed to concat JSON into a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to create a JSON array by randomly selecting JSON object but the JSON array is empty.

I checked that my random function works and it grabs a JSON and it's the case

```
static getNearbyClasses(nb_class) {
        var jsonClasses = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ClassDetailsData.Classes));
        var nearbyClasses = []
        for(let k=0; k < nb_class; k++){
            var randomnb = Utils.getRandomInt(jsonClasses.length-1)
            var randomClass = jsonClasses[randomnb]
            console.log("-----" + randomnb + "---------")
            console.log(randomClass)
            nearbyClasses.concat(randomClass)
        }
        console.log(nearbyClasses)
        return nearbyClasses
    }
```

but `nearbyClasses` is still null. `randomClass` always have a JSON object

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: this `nearbyClasses.concat(randomClass)` should be             `nearbyClasses=nearbyClasses.concat(randomClass)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the selected answer, if you don't want a new array is to use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/push):

```
nearbyClasses.push(...randomClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) doesn't change the original array but returns a new array after merging them.

So in this line:

```js
nearbyClasses.concat(randomClass);
```

The new returned array by concat is not assigned to `nearbyClasses` and `nearbyClasses` will not be changed.

To fix this just change it to:

```
nearbyClasses = nearbyClasses.concat(randomClass);
```